# Move rspec cases in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My `rspec` directory is beginning to get a little cluttered, so I moved all the specs to a `cases` directory.  Upon doing so rspec stopped treating `*_controller_spec.rb` as `:type => :controller`.  What is the magic way to get this behavior back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant comment form [a discussion on the rspec-rails github page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/600#issuecomment-7946929):

> The integration rspec-rails provides for the various spec types is based on modules that get included example groups based on the convention of which directory the spec files are in. Have a look at the [example folder](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/master/lib/rspec/rails/example) to see all the modules that get included each spec type. [example.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb) wires it all up based on the file_path.
>
> You'll need to do this wiring yourself since you're outside of the "normal" conventions for rspec-rails. You can either include the modules manually in each example group, use metadata to tag the example groups with their type, and include based on the type, or use a similar file_path convention approach as rspec-rails does.

So basically, make a copy of [this file](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb) and replace all the `spec` in calls to `escaped_path` by `spec cases`, then paste that into your `RSpec::configure` block. There might be an easier way to do it, this is just what I found after googling for a few seconds (never actually tried this myself).

Comment: "rspec directory structure" returned that link as the fourth result.

Comment: Thanks. Should have been a little more generic in my search.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you had files named like `spec/foo_controller_spec.rb`, the "right" way to do it is to put them in a directory named `controllers`. So you get `spec/controllers/foo_controller_spec.rb`.

The [readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#readme) for rspec-rails goes into detail on which kind of spec goes in which directory.

Comment: Everything was in `spec/controllers`. Now they're in `spec/cases/controllers`. I'm not looking for the standard way to do it.